# Using a (varying) variable to update gl_PointSize has strange behavior in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl

I am trying to dynamically set the point size of my vertexes and I am only able to do so if I use a static non-changing value:

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout(location = 4) uniform float Size = 50;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    gl_PointSize = Size;
}
```

Result:
[image]

However when I try to update them dynamically I see that only one of the vertices sizes change and the others disappear entirely:

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout(location = 4) in float Size;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    gl_PointSize = Size;
}
```

Which I then set it's value:

```
def drawWithoutVBOs(vertices, indices):
    ...
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4)
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 50)
    glDrawElementsus(GL_POINTS, indices)
```

Result:
[image]

Could someone please help me spot what I am doing wrong?

---

*Sourcecode for this project*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import time

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy

width = 640
height = 480

vertices = numpy.array([0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                       -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        0.5, -0.5, 0.0], numpy.float32)
indices = numpy.array([0, 1, 2], numpy.ushort)

def init():
    vertexShader = compileShader("""
        #version 450 core

        layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
        layout(location = 4) in float Size;
        //layout(location = 4) uniform float Size = 50;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = vPosition;
            gl_PointSize = Size;
        }""", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentShader = compileShader("""
        #version 450 core

        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader)
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition")
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 4, "Size")
    glLinkProgram(program)
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE) #allow the program to specify the point size

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    return program

def drawWithoutVBOs(vertices, indices):
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices)

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4)
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 50)
    glDrawElementsub(GL_POINTS, indices)
    #glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, indices.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)

    program = init()
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glUseProgram(program)

    drawWithoutVBOs(vertices, indices)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `glDrawElementsus(GL_POINTS, indices)` is that just a typo or is there a `glDrawElementsus` method?

Comment: It's a valid [function](http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~matos/cg/docs/manual/glDrawElements.3G.html), equivalent in this case to: `glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, indices.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)`

Comment: when you are defining array and calling glVertexAttribPointer with index 4 you don't provide pointer to data as the last argument. In C it would defenetly read 3 elements from address 50. So you should specify your Sizes array like you did with vertices

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, if I understand correctly I removed the const. `50` and replaced with `new_pt_size = 50`. I also updated the example, but did not seem to have an effect.

Comment: No, you should process pt_size in the same way like verticies. Add pt_size = [1,2,3] below verticies array and pass it as argument. It has to contain same number elements as number of verticies. 3 in your case.

Comment: Cool, changing to `new_pt_size = [50,50,50]` then it works fine. Thanks! Guess I thought that float accepted only a single value (while float[3] would be used for array??).